# PhD, Ph.D. and Ph.D

Tags: terminology

According to the [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/phd):

> **PhD** in British
>
> abbreviation for
>
> **Doctor of Philosophy**

Well in American

> **PhD** in American or **Ph.D.**
>
> Doctor of Philosophy

But sometimes I also see it's abbreviated to "**Ph.D**".

Questions: Is **PhD** the only form used in British? And in American, both **PhD** and **Ph.D.** are acceptable? What about "**Ph.D**"? Is it used in some other areas?

Comment: "Ph.D" is internally inconsistent. Either you use the practice of using "." to indicate omitted characters or you don't.

Comment: pH D could also mean the pH value of Deuterium.  Context is what makes these differences clear for the most part.

Comment: @Neil, I am only talking about the abbreviation of Doctor of Philosophy.

Comment: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/phd?fallbackFrom=british-grammar&q=PhD) and [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/ph.d.) both disagree with Collins about whether Americans use "PhD". However, these broad-stroke generalisations work very poorly in an increasingly multicultural world. Agree with @jsheeran about "Ph.D" being plain inconsistent.

Comment: I'd like to know where you've seen it abbreviated as "Ph.D" – was it in reputable sources like published books, news articles, and published curricula from reputable institutions? Or merely in occasional discussion threads or online chats? It sounds like simple careless typing to me.

Comment: @J.R. It could be careless typing and I can't find out where I have seen it. So, is "Ph.D." used in American?

Comment: Sure, but periods with abbreviations are slowly slipping out of vogue.

Comment: You'll find that British usage varies, especially informally.  However, whereas in the 1950s it was normal in Britain to use full stops in "Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ph.D.", "etc.", etc, in present-day British English such usage is much rarer, especially in printed material.